# CSS with :After :NTH-Child

Tags: html, css

```css
.app-btn {
  font-size: 0px !important;
}

.app-btn:after {
  content: '+2500';
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 15px !important;
}

.app-btn:after:nth-child(1) {
  content: "+18000";
}

.app-btn:after:nth-child(2) {
  content: "+14000";
}
```

```html
<div class="app" data-url="#">
  <button class="app-btn">CHANGE</button>
</div>

<div class="app" data-url="#">
  <button class="app-btn">CHANGE</button>
</div>

<div class="app" data-url="#">
  <button class="app-btn">CHANGE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `.app:nth-child(2) > .app-btn:after`

Comment: `::after` does not replace existing content. You need Javascript for that, or remove the pre-existing content "CHANGE". Next, you have the wrong order in your selector. Instead, use `.app-btn:nth-child(1)::after`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a problem with the CSS selector being used.  These don't match the buttons:

```
.app-btn:after:nth-child(1) { ... }
.app-btn:after:nth-child(2) { ... }
```

In fact, each button is a sole child of the parent `div` so that selector doesn't actually make sense.

Instead, use the `nth-child` on the parent div (or, potentially, `nth-of-type`) and then apply the style to the descendent `app-btn`:

```
.app:nth-child(1) > .app-btn:after { ... }
.app:nth-child(2) > .app-btn:after { ... }
```

The following snippet shows this in action:

```css
.app > .app-btn {
  font-size: 0px !important;
}

.app > .app-btn:after {
  content: '+2500';
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 15px !important;
}

.app:nth-child(1) > .app-btn:after {
  content: "+18000";
}

.app:nth-child(2) > .app-btn:after {
  content: "+14000";
}
```

```html
<div class="app" data-url="#">
    <button class="app-btn">CHANGE</button>
</div>
<div class="app" data-url="#">
    <button class="app-btn">CHANGE</button>
</div>
<div class="app" data-url="#">
    <button class="app-btn">CHANGE</button>
</div>
```